# How can I define alkenes using graph theory?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, hydrocarbons

I want to represent alkenes in a mathematical fashion but I want to make sure of what I'm writing. Here is what I tried by defining "alkenic" graphs:

Alkenic graphs are connected non-looped multigraphs where:

- nodes are of degree less than 5 (octet rule);
- there is at least a double edge and no triple or quadruple ones (edges like in bonds);
- cyclic submultigraphs with conjugated single-double edges given in any conjugation order are to be considered isomorphic (anti aromatic or aromatic isomorphism).
  For example, the graphs representing "1,4-dimethylcyclobuta-1,3-diene" and "1,2-dimethylcyclobuta-1,3-diene" are isomorphic.

In this case I'm not taking stereoisomers into account.

Comment: [Assistance requested in Math.SE Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37126391#37126391).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could just represent them as simple weighted graphs? Edges of weight 1 represent single bonds, while edges of weight 2 represent double-bonds.

*Edit: For condition #3 simply pick a canonical ordering for the vertices/atoms. See

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization

http://depth-first.com/articles/2006/08/12/inchi-canonicalization-algorithm/

for examples

Comment: Ok, but what about condition 3?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer